# Barcode crash without errors

Tags: flutter, barcode

I am making an app using the qrCode scanner and when i open the app on my iphone and touch the button for the qrCode scanning it shuts down automatically , not opening even the camera.I used barcode_scan in pubspec.yaml and the code is:

```
String qrResult = "Not yet Scanned";
    onPressed: () async {
                    String scaning = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
                    setState(() {
                      qrResult = scaning;
                    });
                  },
```

The app is made in flutter

Comment: Not sure if it will help you debug this issue, but try to put all your await methods in a try...catch block. Will help with debugging

Comment: Please check you have asked for camera permission in info.plist as you are checking on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Please You can use this package [flutter_barcode_scanner 1.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner/) to make your Work Simple.Cheers!!

Comment: It support both QR and Barcode,Please check Example Section..

Answer (score 0):

```
    scan() async {                                                 
   try {
         dynamic bar = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
       if(bar != null && bar.isNotEmpty){
          print(" scanning qrcode ------------------------ $barcode");
     setState(() {
       barcode = bar;
     });
    }} on PlatformException catch (e) {
     setState(() => this.barcode = '');
  
   } on FormatException{
  setState(() => this.barcode = '');
   } catch (e) {
  setState(() => this.barcode = '');
   }
 }
```